# Misbehaving reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

My reputation is acting out.

Earlier today, I've hit 200 rep. Great.

Then, my rep went back down to 185, because an answer of mine, that was accepted this morning, later got unaccepted. That's fine.

Then weirdness starts: I see my posts getting upvotes, but no reputation change. So, for some reason, my rep got stuck at 185.

More important to me, the counter for the 'Legendary' badge got an extra day on it when I hit 200 rep, then went back when I got back to 185. And since I'm stuck on 185, I can't get that day back on the counter.

That's a bug, right? Even if the reputation is somehow right, the counter for the badge should go up when I hit that day's cap, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've noticed similar weirdnesses on my account (aiming for the lessor Epic badge). I read on the main Meta to find out about it and was glad to see that, even if you end your day with <200, it will count towards the badges as long as it did hit 200 at some point.  Check it now and see if that's right (it might only be if there were 200 from upvotes alone). My annoyance is that if I get a downvote then an upvote and end up >200, the downvotes had no effect on the pts I can carry over. But if the downvote comes later, it sticks. But at least I can still get a ticker towards the badge w/ 198.

Comment: @Cyn I can't check now - that was over two months ago, I don't actually remember how what I had on the badge counter back then. I too remember reading that the day should still count towards the badge, but then I saw the counter going back down that day. And yeh, the part about the late-night -2 is unfair, counter-intuitive and annoying. I would have expected it to balance out.

Comment: Whoops, I misread it as March 8th, not Jan.  It popped up on the question list because of  an edit yesterday.  Somehow I missed it in Jan.  I'm still catching up after my trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's just that reputation gets really difficult once you hit the rep cap. Works-as-designed.

Here is what I found out:

- The accept happened *not* on 8th January, but on 6th January
- You had a total of 213 reputation for 6th January - 200 from positive stuff, one downvote and the acceptance giving you additional 15
- on 8th you got 200 reputation
- on 8th the acceptance was reversed - but that reverses the acceptance on the *original* day according to [this older meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173729/352819)

  - the 6th lost 15 points and was now at a total of 198 - which is below the 200 threshold needed for the badge
  - to not mess with the display of the old reputation data (you *did* gain 213 reputation on the 6th after all) the 15 reputation were alloted for the 8th - but you did get 200 reputation for *that* day through other means, it just displays as 185 because your total rep did that change

Therefore the counter is working as designed. On 6th it got raised. On 8th it got raised when you hit the rep cap. Then the unacceptance happened and the 6th was reversed - leaving it one lower than before, which is what you saw.